# How to load gdal from python 2.7.8 on win7 32bit using arcgis python 2.7.8?

Tags: gdal, windows

My Python installation is:

`Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win3s`

gdal installation file:

```
gdal-202-1500-core.msi
```

I have installed the following python binaries:

```
GDAL-2.2.1.win32-py2.7.msi
```

I  put GDAL in the "Path" system variable:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL`

PYTHON_PATH - `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\DLLs;C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL`

GDAL_DATA - `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_data`

GDAL_DRIVER_PATH - `C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_plugins`

But still after a new start of windows I get the following message when trying to load gdal in python:

```
import error: dll load failed
```

what else can I do to run gdal in python?

Comment: Python doesn't like spaces in path names.

Comment: Then why does gdal install inself into C:\Program Files (x86) ?????